# How can chaining one method onto another change the original method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

The easiest way to explain this conundrum is with an example:

Say I have two **Mongoid** models which are related via a `has_many` relationship:
A Blog post

```
class Post
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :body, type: String
   
   has_many :comments
end
```

and it's comments

```
class Comment
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :text, type: String
   
   belongs_to :post
end
```

Now I create a Post which has two comments in IRB, and I attempt to load them via the relationship. I have some DB logging enabled so I can see when the query is made:

```
post.comments #=>
 2016-04-27 13:51:52.144 [DEBUG MONGODB | localhost:27017 | test.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"comments", "filter"=>{"post_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('571f315e5a4e491a6be39e02')}}]
 2016-04-27 13:51:52.150 [DEBUG MONGODB | localhost:27017 | test.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000492643s]
 => [#<Comment _id: 571f315e5a4e491a6be39e03, text: 'great post' >, #<Comment _id: 571f315e5a4e491a6be39e12, text: 'this!' >]
```

So the comments are loaded from the DB and returned as a `Mongoid::Relations::Targets::Enumerable` class, which looks like an array, and it contains the two comments.

Now when I open a fresh IRB console, and take a look at the criteria used to load these comments using the `criteria` attribute of the `Mongoid::Relations::Targets::Enumerable` class instance `post.comments`, I get this output:

```
post.comments.criteria #=>
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
 selector: {"post_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('571f315e5a4e491a6be39e02')}
 options:  {}
 class:    Comment
 embedded: false>
```

How come no DB requests is made in this example? It's not a caching problem as I opened a new IRB console.

How can chaining `criteria` onto `post.comments` change what the `.comments` method does?
I took a look through Mongoid's implementation of the `Mongoid::Relations::Targets::Enumerable` class ([source on Github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/relations/targets/enumerable.rb)), but couldn't find any clues to how it works.

---

## Edit

To clarify the question:

This code, doesn't query the database:

```
post.comments.criteria
```

But this code does:

```
foo = post.comments
post.comments.criteria
```

How come?

Comment: Are you asking how `post.comments.criteria` is showing the ObjectId selector? If so, your `post` is a variable (of the Post class) and it comes from there. Because the `post` variable is a Post class, it understands that #comments is a relationship (has_many). In short, I believe a DB call was made when your `post` variable was initialized.

Comment: It isn't going to make a DB call until you use a query method (See: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-queries/).

Comment: @wes.hysell Thank you for the comments. If it shouldn't make a DB call at all, then why is it doing so for me? I'm using `Mongoid` version 5.1.3 and rails `4.2.6`

Comment: You mention that you are running this in IRB console. The IRB console runs inspect on the returned object (`foo`). If you make the command `foo = post.comments and nil` you should notice that the db is not queried. Then, you can simply run the command `foo` and that should query the database because the IRB console will run #inspect on the returned object. This is the effect of IRB console.

Comment: @wes.hysell Off course, that's it. The console prints the output of the command run. As `Mongoid::Relations::Targets::Enumerable`'s inspect method calls inspect on the `entries`, it has to make the query to show them. Thank you!

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer:

When executing [Mongoid::Relations::Targets::Enumerable#inspect](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908204506/http://www.rubydoc.info:80/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/Targets/Enumerable#inspect-instance_method), the inspect method is executed on all of the entries:

> Inspection will just inspect the entries for nice array-style printing.

This cannot be done without the use of a query method.

The question the OP is actually having is more related with the IRB console. The IRB console processes this response object in a way that triggers `#inspect` and, in turn, a query method. For Mongoid (and ActiveRecord) classes, the #inspect method executesa query in order to produce the expected result.

By example, this will trigger a query to the database if ran in the IRB console:

```
>> foo = posts.comments
>> post.comments.criteria
```

The response of `foo` will trigger a query method when the IRB console attempts to output the object as a response. The query to the db can be suppressed in the IRB console in (at least) one of two ways:

**Method 1: `and nil`**

Essentially, you can suffix a single command with `and nil` or `;0` or something similar to prevent the first command from being processed by IRB's response output. This is because the IRB console only looks at the last object (like a ruby method's return).

```
>> foo = posts.comments and nil
>> post.comments.criteria
```

The above will not query the database, because the output processed by IRB on the first line is `nil` instead of the `foo` variable.

**Method 2: `conf.echo = false`**

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284331/1483788

This method prevents the IRB console from processing response objects automatically.

```
>> conf.echo = false    
>> foo = posts.comments
>> post.comments.criteria
```

This will not query the database from within the console. However, you will not get a response from the last line, either. You will need to use `puts` or `pp` (pretty print) to output the object. By comparison, if you run the command `foo.inspect` while using this method, you will notice a query to the db is executed in order to the produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

`post.comments` is what you would call a "Query object". In other words, it contains all the necessary information to fetch the required data from the database, but not the data itself. When you call `post.comments.criteria` it's simply displaying the relevant parameters which the query object stores in order to make the request. The object id is available here because `post` already exists in memory.

The same principle would apply to `post.comments.to_sql` if you were using a sql database.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Anthony. I understand how the query object works. I've edited the question to clarify what I was asking